# Firing_Delay not set before reading

Tags: compiler-errors, game-maker-studio-2

RN im using a tutorial, and I have been following it to the letter, but my code still wont run

```
x = oPlayer.x;
y = oPlayer.y+10;

image_angle = point_direction(x,y,mouse_x,mouse_y);

firingdelay = firingdelay - 1;
if (mouse_check_button(mb_left)) && (firingdelay < 0)
{
    firingdelay = 5;
    with (instance_create_layer(x,y, "Bullet", oBullet))
    {
        speed = 25;
        direction = other.image_angle;
        image_angle = direction;
    }
}
```

Is there anything I need to alter to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

`... is not set before reading it` in gml usually means a nullreference exception. It's trying to use a variable before it exists.

Is it `firingdelay` or `Firing_Delay`? You're using the latter in the title. 
In code, those would be two seperate variables.

I think you need to declare `firingdelay = 5` in the Create Event.